# How to detect selected word and change the background of input field with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select list, it has class `.topics` as follows

- Countries

  - United States of America
  - United Kingdom
- Science

  - Physics
  - Chemistry
- Health
- History

and have an input text field, it has class `.body`. if user write any word which is selected as `topic` than i want to change the background color of the body to red. How do i achieve this thing with jQuery? I tried my best to solve it but i don't know why my mind wasn't getting to starting point. Thanks for giving me a hint as i am new to jQuery.

Comment: The deal here is, you post what you tried, then we help you fix it. we don't write your code for you. Atleast make the attempt

Comment: i am learning jquery and just dont understand from where should i start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For someone who is new to Jquery it can seem daunting, but if you familiarize yourself with the Jquery Docs here: http://api.jquery.com/ you will find that Jquery is one of the easiest languages to ever learn, and you can get a good handle on it in as little as a few months.

here is a commented solution to your question, and i hope that it helps you understand a bit how Jquery works. it will seem confusing at first, but if you read enough about anonymous functions and callbacks, you will pick it up in no time.

```
$(function(){ //this is a shortcut to document ready function

    var selected = null;//first, we need to define a variable called selected. 
    //when  the val() of .topics changes, 
    //this will house the text value of the currently selected option.

    $(document).on('change','.topics',function(){ 
    //detect a change in the document only relative to the 
    //.topics class, according to another post, 
    //this works with dynamically generated dom elements.

        selected = $('.topics').val();//set the value of selected in global 
        //scope so we can use it in our body keyup

    });

    $('.body').keyup(function(){ //detect when a user is typing in the .body element(s)

        if($(this).val() == selected) //if the value of the element equals the same as the select option
        {
            $(this).css('background-color','red');//make the background red.
        }else{
            if($(this).css('background-color') == 'red'){
                $(this).css('background-color','');//fall back to default
            }
        }
    });

});
```